# Sqlite3 insert error C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am inserting to sqlite3 table Company where i used following schema to create table

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
         "NAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,"
         "ADDRESS           TEXT    NOT NULL;";
```

I am able to create table, but when I use following command to insert using sqlite3_bind_text, I am getting following problem as

```
const char* sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY(NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES (?, ?)"
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, &stmt, &zErrMsg);
if(rc == SQLITE_OK ) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "abc", 3, 0);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "def", 3, 0);
    // commit
    sqlite3_step(stmt) ;
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt) ;
}
```

I am getting error like, 
    SQL ERROR: COMPANY.NAME may not be NULL

Does sqlite3 bind text not work when column is not null?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, and I've never used `bind_text` before, but why don't you simply use `sqlite3_exec`? For me, I'd just call `sqlite3_exec` twice and insert the values, but I may just be misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: slqite3_exec is perfect, I just wanted to manipulate const char * if I need to add more values like 10 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const char* sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY(NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES (?, ?)"
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *pszTest ;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, &pszTest) ;
if(rc == SQLITE_OK ) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "abc", 3, 0);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "def", 3, 0);
    // commit
    sqlite3_step(stmt) ;
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i forget to add setp and finalize in my question. But, I have this in code and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you change the exec api to  sqlite3_prepare ?

Comment: Yes, I it wasn't working. But, somehow it worked with your answer. Thanks a lot.